# systemctl testing shell scripts

Tags: linux, archlinux, systemd

So I am trying arch linux, but I can't really understand how to make autostart scripts and such. I tried this (I know there are better ways to do it but it's just a test):

this is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=testing purposes
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/font
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this is the script:

```
setfont Lat2-Terminus16
```

I chmod +x'd the script and stuff so I thought it wouldn't make any problems but it does not work unlike what I expected, so I am clearly doing something wrong. Where is the problem?

EDIT: Solved, I changed the ExecStart line to this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/setfont Lat2-Terminus16'
```

Comment: Could be failing because the script is lacking a shebang line: `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks thomas, but that was not the problem (i think). Apparently at the time systemd starts there is no $PATH, so the system didnt know how to handle the script.